# 2 way Databinding with ViewModel-SavedState

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, 2-way-object-databinding, viewmodel-savedstate

I have a subscription form: Name, Address, Local, etc, etc... and I want to be able to use `Data Binding`, `LiveData` and `SavedStateHandle` to handle and persist data.

Let's assume: 1 way `Data Binding`, `LiveData` and `SavedStateHandle`

```
private val _name: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = stateHandle.getLiveData("_name", "")
val name: LiveData<String> = _name

fun onNameChanged(editable: Editable) {
    _name.value = editable.toString()
}

<EditText
    android:text="@{viewModel.name}"
    android:afterTextChanged="@{viewModel::onNameChanged}"
    ...
/>
```

This works but I think we can do better:

- `@Parcelize class Form` to encapsulate all fields
- `2-way Data Binding` to reduce `.xml` code

Now the problems start to appear.
How can I be notified of a change inside `Form class` in order to be able to persist the `object` with `SavedState`? Is there actually an advantage trying to improve the code above or with `2-way Data Binding` we are losing control? I'm also using some logic to enable the submit button like this:

```
private val _name: MutableLiveData<String> = stateHandle.getLiveData("_name", "")   
val name = _name.map { value -> {
    updateUi()
    return value}
}

private val _formValidLiveData = MutableLiveData<Unit>()
val submitEnable = _formValidLiveData.map { _ -> isFormValid() }
val submitAlpha = _formValidLiveData.map { _ -> if (isFormValid()) 1f else 0.5f }
...
private fun updateUi() {
    _formValidLiveData.value = Unit
}
```

Again, with `2-way Data Binding` I'm losing control, how can I call `updateUi()` when a `EditText` field change?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you check this document https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way?

Comment: If you want to use two-way binding, why not use `public val name: MutableLiveData<Boolean>`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, actually that's a good point, I completely missed. But now how can I apply a Transformation to that MutableLiveData? Because I want to perform a updateUi() for UX purpose, every time a field changes. Question 2: how can I have a data class (or a class) capable of being stored with SavedState and where its fields are two-way binded?

Comment: Ah that's tricky, you can define a private MediatorLiveData that triggers the internal changes which always observes this MutableLiveData.

Comment: why don't you just `stateHandle.set(KEY, VALUE)` without having to care for a `MutableLiveData`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, was stuck with a similar problem - and tested this, which seems to work fine:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

  public final MutableLiveData<String> mUsername;
  private SavedStateHandle handle;

  public LoginViewModel(Application application, SavedStateHandle handle) {
    // If this is the first time entering the activity, mUsername will be created, populated by value 'BLAH' and stored in the handler.
    // else, this will will be the last set value
    mUsername = handle.getLiveData("mUsername", "BLAH");
  }
}
```

Now, I entered some values in the 2-way binded user name field, defined like so in xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     android:id="@+id/username_wrapper"
     android:layout_below="@id/header_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/general_padding"
     android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
     android:hint="@string/username">
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/username_field"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
           android:text="@={ viewModel.mUsername }"/>
      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

To test, I enetered some data into the field and I followed the answer linked below. The field was set to the LATEST entered value every time. To make sure, I also put a breakpoint in the constructor of my view model - and you can see that the value is populated correctly! So, it seems two way databinding works fine.

Link to trigger activity / viewmodel destroy on navigate away: [Android viewModel savedStateHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232000/android-viewmodel-savedstatehandle)

Comment: This will only update the value of mUsername. How do we know the value is also updated in SavedStateHandle?